# Is there a function in python that returns which element from list appeared most times inside list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have list like a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1] and in that list "1" is the element which appeared most times, is there a function which can detect that "1" has appeared most times? Is it even possible to detect? I need to generate random list and detect which element appeared most times in it, that is the main problem.

Comment: `max(a, key=a.count)`

Comment: "Is it even possible", lol. No, that's mathematically impossible. Counting numbers is very hard for computers.